# How do I pass a value from JavaScript to C# using jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a variable whose value I calculate in JavaScript. I want to pass that variable to C# to delete a record in the database. This is the code I'm using right now:

```html
<div>
    <h4>Example 2</h4>
    <div class="indent">
        <p class="center"><img src="assets/ex2.jpg" /></p>
        <p class="right">
            <button onclick='
                $.msgbox("Are you sure that you want to permanently delete the selected element?",
                    {
                        type: "confirm",
                        buttons : [
                            {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
                            {type: "submit", value: "No"},
                            {type: "cancel", value: "Cancel"}
                        ]
                    }, 
                    function(result) { 
                        $("#result2").text(result); 
                    } 
                );
            '>
                Example 2
            </button>
            <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />  
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click" />
            Result: <span id="result2"></span>
    </div>
```

How do I pass the variable from JavaScript to C#?

Comment: This question depends a lot on your framework.  If this is MVC, you might create a controller or Web API, then do a AJAX POST to it.  If this is some other web tech, you may do a Web Service, Page Method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using hidden field. Set the value of the hidden field through the jquery code and fetch the hidden field value through the server side code c#

Comment: Is it possible to change my code or give an example please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516293/how-to-access-a-javascript-variable-from-code-behind-in-asp-net/9516343#9516343

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to first change the button to the server side so you can add access server code
   like the one below:

   ```
   < asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" onClientClick="Your javascript code" />
   ```
2. you can add the **`javascript`** in **`onClientClick`** event
3. Add the value of the variable to hidden field..
   adding

   ```
   $("#inpHide").val(result);
   ```

Comment: And why exactly are you posting two different answers?

Comment: When giving answer it is not quite clean and clear in the comment with code

Comment: Thanks for the answer would have to replace $ ("# result2"). Text (result); than $ ("# inpHide"). Val (result); Use