# How to pass Javascript Value to a method in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is my radio button list

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="geo_radio" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" >                             
    <asp:ListItem Value="state">State</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="county">County</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="county subdivision">County Subdivision</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="place">Place</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="micropolitan">Micropolitan</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="combined statistical area">Combined Statistical Area</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="congressional districts">Congressional Districts</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Custom Region">Custom Region</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I am able to retrieve selected value using

```
$('#<%=geo_radio.ClientID%>').find('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
});
```

In my .aspx page I have a method FetchData(). I am calling this function on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FetchData();   
}
```

How can I send selected radio button value to FetchData() function.

Comment: Does this help:- http://forums.asp.net/t/1251247.aspx/2/10 ??

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516293/how-to-access-a-javascript-variable-from-code-behind-in-asp-net

Comment: Any reason to avoid  retrieving the value on the postback event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden field, set the value of asp hidden field, or you can use request object to retrieve the value.

[The Hidden Field class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

add selectedValue to hidden field and get hidden field value to code behind and pass it to your function

```
$("#hid").val(selectedValue);
```

hid is the id or your hidden feild

```
 FetchData(hid.value);
```