# Send JavaScript variable to asp.net webforms code-behind is always empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I was using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9516343/1118218) as a reference for sending a JavaScript variable to my server side. However when I implement that solution everything comes up correctly in the JS `alert()`, but the value of my hidden field when I hit the server is always empty.

JavaScript and Html:

```
<script>
    function rblSelectionChange()
    {
        var selection = $('#inAction input:checked').val();
        var stuff = $('#<%= clientSelection.ClientID %>').val(selection);
        alert(stuff.val());
    }
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="clientSelection" runat="server" />
<div class="row-fluid">
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="inAction" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:ListItem onClick="rblSelectionChange();" Value="RuEp" Text="I remember my <b>username</b>. Please email me a new <b>password</b>." />
        <asp:ListItem onClick="rblSelectionChange();" Value="ReEu" Text="I remember my <b>email</b>. Please email me my <b>username</b>." />
        <asp:ListItem onClick="rblSelectionChange();" Value="ReEup" Text="I remember my <b>email</b>. Please email me my <b>username</b> and a new <b>password</b>." />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

On the submit event of the page I try to grab the value and it is empty:

```
protected void btnActionSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selection = clientSelection.Value;
    ...snip...
}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

### Update

I have tried to change my hidden field to a pure html one, not the asp: control.

```
<input type="hidden" id="clientSelection" name="clientSelection" value="" />
```

I have modified the code-behind as follows:

```
private string _selection = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //_selection = clientSelection.Value.ToString();
    if (IsPostBack)
        _selection = Request.Form["clientSelection"];
}
```

I am still getting nothing for the value Request.Form["clientSelection"]. Important note however is it works in Chrome, FF, and IE10. The browser I am trying to get it to work in is IE 7 8 and 9. I am fully stumped.

### Update 2

Per request, here is the source of the page when I inspect it in IE10 (with browser and document mode set to IE7)

```
<DIV id=ctl00_cphBodyWithForm_htmActionSelect class=row-fluid>
    <P class=lead>Can't access your account? Please select from the following options: </P>
    <SCRIPT>
                function rblSelectionChange()
                {
                    var selection = $('#inAction input:checked').val();
                    var stuff = $('#ctl00_cphBodyWithForm_clientSelection').val(selection);
                    alert(stuff.val());
                }
    </SCRIPT>
    <INPUT id=ctl00_cphBodyWithForm_clientSelection type=hidden name=ctl00$cphBodyWithForm$clientSelection jQuery191034119593101524303="7"> 
    <DIV class=row-fluid>
        <TABLE id=inAction border=0>
            <TBODY>
            <TR>
             <TD><INPUT onclick=rblSelectionChange(); id=inAction_0 type=radio value=RuEp name=ctl00$cphBodyWithForm$inAction jQuery191034119593101524303="8"><LABEL for=inAction_0>I remember my <B>username</B>. Please email me a new <B>password</B>.</LABEL></TD>
             </TR>
             ...snip...
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
     </DIV>
     <DIV class=span12>
        <A class="submitButton roundedBR" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphBodyWithForm$ctl00','')">Continue &gt; </A>
     </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Can't you use `inAction.SelectedValue` in code-behind file?

Comment: for some reason inAction.SelectedValue is always coming in null for IE 7 8 and 9. Which is the root cause of me trying a kludgy solution.

Comment: Try **Request.Form["clientSelection"]** instead.

Comment: Try using `UniqueID` instead of `ClientID`.

Comment: Tried Request.Form["clientSelection"] and UniqueID, both not working.

Comment: Can you please click `View Source` in your browser and paste the javascript and HTML that is emitted? Also please show where you are binding your `rblSelectionChange()` handler.

Comment: @davidisawesome so the only reason you are trying to do this is because "inAction.SelectedValue is always coming in null for IE 7 8 and 9"? So really you can fix that and dump the javascript option? Which doesn't appear to be doing anything but putting one form value into another form value.

Comment: And just for giggles, can you remove the spaces when you build your selector: `$('#<%=clientSelection.ClientID%>').val(selection);`

Comment: @MikeSmithDev yes, I can dump the js solution if there is one where the value is coming back correctly for those browsers within some js trickery.

Comment: @davidisawesome I would recommend validating your HTML... I've not really come across an issue where form values don't post, which is why I think there is another issue altogether.

Comment: @ChrisHardie I posted the raw js and html in the question.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Sweet baby jesus, I feel like a rookie here, but running it through a validator showed me some weird closing form tag issues, removed the error and it seems to be working now. Why??

Comment: I don't see what would be causing the issue. Do you have any other code that disables your form controls? That would be the only thing I can think off that would prevent the value from posting. Are you able to bring up the Network tab in IE's dev tools and look at the posted values in the request?

Comment: @davidisawesome why? Because invalid HTML is invalid ;) Glad it fixed it. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your HTML through a validator. If your form values aren't posting in certain browsers, it sounds like you have invalid HTML, and that is the source of your problem.

Once you fix the HTML issue, you can get rid of that JavaScript and simply use the value of `inAction`.

[W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)

You mentioned that you had weird closing form tag issues. A form cannot be placed within a form, so perhaps that was the root of your problem.

Comment: Yup, I had a form for a search box within the main webforms-form. Thanks for the help, and on a side note, MVC ftw.

Comment: Ah, I have to wait 23 hours to award the bounty.