# value not passing from javascript to c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Asp.net

```
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />
```

Javascript

```
function GetUserName() {
        var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        var unamer = document.getElementById('hdnfldVariable');
        unamer.value = wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%");
    }
```

c#

```
string username1 = hdnfldVariable.Value;
```

username1 gets null value. Can anyone check if its correct way to do it?

Comment: `document.getElementById("<%= hdnfldVariable %>");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a JavaScript variable from code behind in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516293/how-to-access-a-javascript-variable-from-code-behind-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly retrieve through page request.

```
 string  username1 = Page.Request.Form["hdnfldVariable"].ToString();
```