# Can't access server side variables from master page

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, master-pages, server-variables

I am trying to access server side variables from master page and keep getting "xxx does not exists in current context" error and can't seem to find out why.

This is how I have defined the variables and how I am trying to access them:

```
namespace ABC
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        public string Version { get { return Global.VersionInfo; } }
        public string Active_server { get { return Global.ipaddress; } }
        public string Environment_Value { get { return Global.Apppliaction_Environment; } }
        public string Is_Authenticated { get { return Session["IsAuthenticated"].ToString(); } }
        public string User_Role { get { return Session["UserRole"].ToString(); } }
        public string User_Name { get { return Session["AceId"].ToString(); } }
        public string Session_ID { get { return Session["SessionID"].ToString(); } }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
...
}

<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="ABC.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Access Code-Behind Data in Javascript
        var Role = '<%=User_Role%>';
        var UserName = '<%=User_Name%>';
        var VersionValue = '<%=Version%>';
        var EnvironmentValue = '<%=Environment_Value%>';
        var IsAuthenticated = '<%=Is_Authenticated %>';
        var Session_ID = '<%=Session_ID %>';
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Just directly access the variable in your HTML code using this  <%# User_Role.ToString() %> instead? Alternatively, it looks like a bit of effort to do it in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516293/how-to-access-a-javascript-variable-from-code-behind-in-asp-net

Comment: access your variables directly in your HTML Markup.

Comment: How I have it listed and set up is correct. Seems the problem was elsewhere! I had copied global.asax from my other project and when you open it to make modifications, it opens the .cs file. I changed in .cs file the namespace to match my current project namespace but forgot to do the same in global.asax (had to right click on global.asax and select "View markup"). Once that was done, it was fine again.